# can we run ftp or sftp from single user account?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sftp, ftp, file-server

I have installed ftp and sftp on my linux mint system, for wordpress file transfer

I had to create new user account for ftp and sftp on my system during the installation process.

Is it possible to run ftp and sftp from home user account, if yes, how to configure it.

And if single user account access is possible- what is advisable to have - multiple/seperate user accounts for ftp/sftp OR a single account merged with home user should be used

Tried searching for solutions on various forums, but did not get any clarity

Adding for more clarity:

For wordpress, i referred this link [wordpress installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu)

To upload wordpress files to github, i required to convert it to static site, so for using 'simply static' wordpress plugin, i required ftp to upload files from my local wordpress installation.

Below are the links i used for ftp and sftp installation-

I used these 2 links for ftp installation
[ftp install link 1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-20-04) & its [user creation snap](https://ibb.co/pJZNGWr)

[ftp install link 2](https://idroot.us/install-ftp-server-linux-mint-20/) & [its user creation snap](https://ibb.co/J7g1Mtm)

and for sftp
[sftp install link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) & [its user creation snap](https://ibb.co/whhdQY4)

in both ftp and sftp , had to create new users for using them on filezilla/ftp client

So i want to clarify , if I can use my default system user for ftp/sftp access and how to configure it. And what is advisable to create new seperate users and the reason for it.

I searched how and why for cant I use the system user for all these server process, but did not get any clarity from internet

Comment: You mean an sftp server, or a client?

Comment: "I had to create new user account for ftp and sftp on my system during the installation process" - do you mean the system user which runs the daemon?

Comment: Please add the new information and clarifications to the question ([edit] the question). Comments are not for this. Take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SFTP article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) you quoted is misleading at best, and inaccurate for the remainder. SFTP has nothing to do with `vsftpd`.

You can use `sftp` with your own user account already: `sftp you@yourhost`

If you have SFTP you almost certainly do not need to install `vsftpd`. At least, not unless you have a legacy file transfer application you need to support.

In direct response,

> Is it possible to run ftp and sftp from home user account, if yes, how to configure it

Yes. Undo everything in the SFTP document, including the creation of a user account. It was already installed and configured for that.

Comment: i get it , its either FTP+SSL OR SFTP , either of them can be used. As you mentioned for sftp usage, I could use a smilar process as in this link https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-safely-transfer-files/… ... for connecting sftp via terminal . Also want to confirm that for connecting sftp via filezilla, should one use system user name and password https://geekflare.com/connect-sftp-using-filezilla/

Comment: FTP+SSL is not SFTP. (You will sometimes see it as FTP/S, though.)

Comment: oh yes, I meant to say, for the purpose of file transfer I can use (FTP+SSL)  or only (SFTP), either of one.